# adding inline policy to an IAM role

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to add an inline policy to perform OTA update on the hardware (Gigabite-gb-kma1-00). When I click on add inline policy and paste the code in JSON tab, and click review policy and name it, it gives an error "The policy failed legacy parsing"

I tried to remove the gaps before strings and aligned the brackets.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<your_account_id>:role/<your_role_name>"
      }
    ]
}
```

The policy should be successfully created and get added to the IAM role.

Comment: I am suspicious of the values`<your_account_id>` and `<your_role_name>` shown in the policy.  It suggests you are pasting this policy as-is, without making the necessary substitutions.  (If this were the result of redaction, the angle brackets and the word "your" would both be unlikely choices).

Comment: I have added the right account ID as well as role name before selecting review policy